# Using symmetric-key cryptography

Tags: symmetric

A group of 30 people who wish to establish pair-wise secure communications using symmetric-key cryptography. How many KEYS need to be exchanged in total?

Comment: Is this a trick question or extreme laziness? ... 435

Comment: No, it's a real question out of a text book and I am very confused and looking for some help.

Comment: To explain exactly the part you have trouble with (meaning, without rewriting the whole book), it might help if you describe your problem a bit more. What did you try and why, where are you stuck? And/or do you not know what some word means? And/or ...

Comment: It might help to make it simpler; suppose there are 3 people (Alice, Bob, Carol) who wish to establish pair-wise secure communication; how many KEYS need to be exchange in total?  Once you have that, how about 4 people?  Once you see how it works in the small, ramping it up to 30 should be easy...

Answer (score 2):

Let's start off with the fact that there are $n\cdot n$ ordered pairs of *(person, person)*. Now we assume that nobody needs encryption to talk to themselves, so we subtract the $n$ pairs where the person is the same, to get $n\cdot n-n=n(n-1)$. Next, we note that the same secret key can be used to send messages on the route *(A,B)* as on the route *(B,A)* (with proper care taken to avoid reusing the same nonce, etc). So we divide by two to get $n(n-1)/2$. Finally, we plug in $n=30$ to get $30\cdot 29/2=15\cdot 29=435$.

Answer (score 2):

For symmetric pairwise, the minimum would be 435 unique keys.  (N * (N-1)) / 2 unique connections between nodes.

For asymmetric, it would be 30 keys.  Which is one reason asymmetric encryption is so useful.

Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13730546/how-to-prove-max-number-of-connection-between-n-nodes-is-nn-1-2